# How to Dynamically Create ' N' no of Queues in RabbitMQ Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I am trying to create dynamic n Number of Queues using StreamBridge SpringBoot with RabbitMQ as broker
I previous created queue using this method

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sender-in-0.destination=sampleQueue
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sender-in-0.group=processor
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sender-out-0.destination=sampleQueue
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sender-out-0.group=consumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.user-in-0.destination=sampleQueue
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.user-in-0.group=consumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.publisher-out-0.destination=sampleQueue
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.publisher-out-0.group=processor
```

and Having a Producer , Processor and Consumer functions

I have no idea how to dynamically create  1 Producer with 500 queues  to  500 consumers  do I have to config bindings like this is for all 500 or is there any easier method with a loop Queue names could be SampleQueue1,SampleQueue2 so on....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create them ahead of time. Output bindings will be created dynamically, on-demand, see

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_streambridge_and_dynamic_destinations